# Google Maps 3D to Blender not working

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

Hi guys!!I could really use some help. Ive followed the tutorials to convert Google Maps into Blender but this is what appears instead of the landscape. Im not sure why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.